# Failed to mock imports in typescript

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to mock '@unleash/proxy-client-react' by using the mocked function of ts-jest/utils

I did the following

I've created a separate file with content

```
jest.mock('@unleash/proxy-client-react', () => ({
  useUnleashContext: jest.fn(),
  useFlag: jest.fn()
}));
```

This file is added to the list setupFilesAfterEnv of the jest configuration

In test code:

```
import { useUnleashContext } from '@unleash/proxy-client-react';
jest.mock('@unleash/proxy-client-react');
```

and in the beforeEach I call

```
mocked(useUnleashContext).mockClear();
```

This works but when I try to do the same for useFlag I get the following error:

```
TypeError: (0 , utils_1.mocked)(...).mockClear is not a function
```

Can someone help me understand what is happening?

Thanks in advance,
Marco

Answer (score 1):

The only way I was able to make it works is like this:

```
jest.mock('@unleash/proxy-client-react', () => ({
  useUnleashContext: () => jest.fn(),
  useFlag: jest.fn()
}));
```

Comment: Correct, worked for me too however I also had issues with uuid when I added Unleashed I fixed it like this.

in `jest.config.js`

```
  moduleNameMapper: {
...,
    uuid: require.resolve("uuid")
  },
```